# Make the form always get focus even i click another control in C#

Tags: c#, forms, button, focus, picturebox

I made a game with multiple forms in C#

The game use picturebox and button
I use key down event in form with arrow key to make picturebox move...

The problem occur when I click a button that display hidden groupbox.
The button get a focus and when I press my keys to move the picturebox, the picturebox doesn't move. But the focus ring in button move to another button when I press my keys.

I tried clicking my form, set this.focus() and this.select in button click
But nothing above work..

Please help me, this game must be done this saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like homework :)

```
Try setting Form.KeyPreview = true;
```

This will catch all your key presses, regardless of what control has focus.

Comment: Still... not work for me....
I set the form key preview true, but when I click button, it still move the focus ring when i press my keys... T.T